# how can I fix the way printf manage strings with UTF8 and %10s, in c?

Tags: c, string, utf-8, printf, size

I am trying to print a string with non ASCII chars using c and printf, this is the program:

```
include <stdio.h>
void main(void){
  printf("<0123456789> BOTH %s\n","<%5s>");
  printf("<%5s>\n"," w ");
  printf("<%5s>\n"," δ ");
}
```

and I get

```
<0123456789> BOTH <%5s>
<   w >
<  δ >
```

So there is a problem with the size
of strings.
How can I get both strings with the same size?

Comment: Change `printf("<%5s>\n"," δ ");` to `printf("<%6s>\n"," δ ");` for your multi-character character.

Comment: ok, but these solution is manual, I need something automatic, such something to measure visible with and changing printf with that or a function that replace printf for this kind of strings. I do not known in advance how much of these chars I will have in a string. I need to print a table of strings alineated.

Answer (score 1):

Your lowercase delta character is not an 8-bit value. It's represented by two bytes, so printing it with a width specifier of 5 result in it only printing in 4 visible spaces.  You can see the same issue with other Greek letters.

You can further see this by printing the result of `strlen(" δ ")` which prints `4`.

Answer (score 1):

For working with unicode you should use [fwprintf](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=lf-fwprintf-format-data-as-wide-characters-write-stream) instead of `printf`.

See also [7.24.2  Formatted wide character input/output functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).

Comment: I don't believe that wide characters (`wchar_t` and `fwprintf`) are relevant here. OP has specified UTF-8. Non-ASCII Unicode code points are presented by multibyte sequences, rather than wide characters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to count the number of characters printed by a string. There are simplers ....

```
#define ONEMASK ((size_t)(-1) / 0xFF)
#include <stdint.h>
static size_t
cp_strlen_utf8(const char * _s){
//http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html

const char * s;
size_t count = 0;
size_t u;
unsigned char b;

/* Handle any initial misaligned bytes. */
for (s = _s; (uintptr_t)(s) & (sizeof(size_t) - 1); s++) {
    b = *s;

    /* Exit if we hit a zero byte. */
    if (b == '\0')
        goto done;

    /* Is this byte NOT the first byte of a character? */
    count += (b >> 7) & ((~b) >> 6);
}

/* Handle complete blocks. */
for (; ; s += sizeof(size_t)) {
    /* Prefetch 256 bytes ahead. */
    __builtin_prefetch(&s[256], 0, 0);

    /* Grab 4 or 8 bytes of UTF-8 data. */
    u = *(size_t *)(s);

    /* Exit the loop if there are any zero bytes. */
    if ((u - ONEMASK) & (~u) & (ONEMASK * 0x80))
        break;

    /* Count bytes which are NOT the first byte of a character. */
    u = ((u & (ONEMASK * 0x80)) >> 7) & ((~u) >> 6);
    count += (u * ONEMASK) >> ((sizeof(size_t) - 1) * 8);
}

/* Take care of any left-over bytes. */
for (; ; s++) {
    b = *s;

    /* Exit if we hit a zero byte. */
    if (b == '\0')
        break;

    /* Is this byte NOT the first byte of a character? */
    count += (b >> 7) & ((~b) >> 6);
}

done:
    return ((s - _s) - count);
}
```

With these function I could print the complementary number of spaces to alineate next table cell.

Function printf() do not count correctly printed characters. Perhaps printf() must be fixed.

I dont know if these is a universal solution, or if only works for the strings I am using now.